# Are there any instances of any rules for Tabaxi that say they only need 4 hours of rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, rests, tabaxi

One of my players has just started playing a tabaxi, she is sure she read rules that as a racial trait she only needs 4 hours for a long rest. However neither of us can find rules stating this. She is happy not doing it but I just wanted to confirm have these long rest rules ever stood for tabaxi?

I have referred to DnD beyond and have the official rules for tabaxi in physical form and confirmed for 5e it is 8 hours.

What I am asking is if there is a source she may have read, either from an older version of DnD, or pathfinder or an unofficial rule or UA that was not progeressed at all. She accepts it is possible she either mis read or just imagined reading it somewhere.

Comment: This sure sounds like elf, not tabaxi.

Comment: Cats that don't sleep much? Sounds totally legit...

Comment: @MarsPlastic The only way I could see it is if it were part of a larger set of rules where they sleep less during a long rest but have to take at least a few short rest naps during the day or start having problems.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I think they would have to be really active during a long rest - practising how fast they can run around the camp and jumping on the beds of any party members who had been foolish enough to leave their tent open. Then during the day if the party finds a patch of sunlight the tabaxi has to curl up in it and you have to take a short rest.

Comment: I am considering also insisting that if the Tabaxi do this they randomly stop and stare at nothing for just long enough to freak the party out, and then curl up for a nap. Also every morning they must leave a small present of a dead animal at the feet of one of the party :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabaxi were not in 3rd or 4th edition and appear to have been only monsters prior to that, so I think it's unlikely your player is thinking of a rule from a prior edition. What I can find about 2nd edition doesn't mention any special sleeping rules.

Player-character Tabaxi do not seem to have been previewed in Unearthed Arcana, so what's in Volo's Guide is pretty much the whole of it. I see a number of homebrewed catfolk races for Pathfinder and D&D 5th Edition, but nothing that I can locate has any special sleeping rules.

Comment: Tabaxi was in 1e and 2e. See 1981 Fiend Folio.

Comment: Corrected to be more specific about where they weren't. I don't think it really changes the answer any, since it's unlikely somebody would accidentally mix up something printed 40 years ago with current rules text.

Comment: Edition baggage is still pretty common.

Comment: Question specifically asked about older editions, assuming it is only "up to 3.0"  seems unwarranted.

Comment: My library only goes back to 3rd edition, but if you have information about 1e/2e that might help answer the question, feel free to post an answer with it. The information I can find online only lists them as monsters in 2nd ed, and with no special rules about sleeping.

Comment: It would also be rather out of character for them to change the phrasing used in things like the elf and warforged. They probably would note they only need to sleep 4 hours but the long rest still needs to be 8.